# TypeError: Object is not a functon in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm doing user authentication through nodejs.
TypeError: Oject is not function throwing error like this

user.js

```
// get an instance of mongoose and mongoose.Schema
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
// set up a mongoose model and pass it using module.exports
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({
    name: String,
    password: String,
    admin: Boolean
}));
```

server.js

```
User = require('./models/user');
app.get('/setup', function (req, res) {
    // create a sample user
    var nick = new User({ // In this line throwing error Object is not a function.
        name: 'Nick Cerminara',
        password: 'password',
        admin: true
    });
    // save the sample user
    nick.save(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('User saved successfully');
        res.json({
            success: true
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you export in `./models/user` module

Comment: Please check "use model" included successfully?Is it possible share "user model" script?

Comment: I'm importing user.js file.

Comment: Where is the error? What line?

Comment: @gowthamsuneel can you add `console.log(User)` after the require?

Comment: Your code is working fine.
did you connect your database.?
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db_NAME');

Comment: @PPB I made a connection to mongodb